# Flickr API + JAVA - flickrj

Tags: java, api, flickr

I want to download a set of photos of a particular user in Flickr using the Flickr Java API (flickrj)

Does anybody knows how to do it?

I've stated with this code:

```
Transport t = new REST();
Flickr f = new Flickr(key, secret, t);
User u = f.getPeopleInterface().findByUsername("username");
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer before someone could help me.

here's the code:

```
Transport t = new REST();
Flickr f = new Flickr("key", "secret", t);
PhotoList list = f.getPhotosetsInterface().getPhotos("setId", 100, 1);
for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Photo photo = (Photo) iterator.next();
    File file = new File("/tmp/" + photo.getId() + ".jpg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b.write(photo.getOriginalAsStream());
    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, b.toByteArray());
}
```