# java flickr and flickrj download user pictures

Tags: java, flickr, flickrj

Hi I am new to flickrj library. 
Have foundational java knowledge though.
The project that I am working on requires me to authenticate into flickr and then download geo-tagged images into a folder in local hard drive. The program will be Desktop application program.
I am approaching the program by breaking down into 3 steps.
 
1.Proper authentication to be completed.(which i have succeeded)
2.Try to download all the photos that user has when authenticated.
3.Try to alter the code a little so that it will only download geo-tagged images.

My problems is on step 2. I cant download logged-in user images let alone geo-tagged ones.
I am trying the code provided by Daniel Cukier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991623/flickr-api-java-flickrj)
But I am running into problem.
My netbeans simply strike off at the line 77 on .getOriginalAsStream() part, with the error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write"

From my understanding netbeans striking off a line means , it is depreciated but shouldnt it still work? What is holding this whole problem back?

I have tried researching and basically I have to admit , it is beyond my capability to trouble shoot. If anyone has any idea on what i am doing wrong , I would be so grateful.

Ps: I am not looking to be spoon fed but please answer me in idiot-friendly way as I am still a student and my java isn't the greatest.

This code is what I have so far.

```
import com.aetrion.flickr.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.aetrion.flickr.auth.Auth;
import com.aetrion.flickr.auth.AuthInterface;
import com.aetrion.flickr.auth.Permission;
import com.aetrion.flickr.photos.Photo;
import com.aetrion.flickr.photos.PhotoList;
import com.aetrion.flickr.photos.PhotosInterface;
import com.aetrion.flickr.util.IOUtilities;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


public class authenticate {
Flickr f;
RequestContext requestContext;
String frob = "";
String token = "";
Properties properties = null;

public authenticate() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/setup.properties");
        properties = new Properties();

        properties.load(in);
    } finally {
        IOUtilities.close(in);
    }
    f = new Flickr(
        properties.getProperty("apiKey"),
        properties.getProperty("secret"),
        new REST()
    );
    Flickr.debugStream = false;
    requestContext = RequestContext.getRequestContext();
    AuthInterface authInterface = f.getAuthInterface();
    try {
        frob = authInterface.getFrob();
    } catch (FlickrException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("frob: " + frob);
    URL url = authInterface.buildAuthenticationUrl(Permission.DELETE, frob);
    System.out.println("Press return after you granted access at this URL:");
    System.out.println(url.toExternalForm());
    BufferedReader infile =
      new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader (System.in) );
    String line = infile.readLine();
    try {
        Auth auth = authInterface.getToken(frob);
        System.out.println("Authentication success");
        // This token can be used until the user revokes it.
        System.out.println("Token: " + auth.getToken());
        System.out.println("nsid: " + auth.getUser().getId());
        System.out.println("Realname: " + auth.getUser().getRealName());
        System.out.println("Username: " + auth.getUser().getUsername());
        System.out.println("Permission: " + auth.getPermission().getType());

        PhotoList list = f.getPhotosetsInterface().getPhotos("72157629794698308", 100, 1);
        for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Photo photo = (Photo) iterator.next();
        File file = new File("/tmp/" + photo.getId() + ".jpg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.write(photo.getOriginalAsStream());
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, b.toByteArray());
}






    } catch (FlickrException e) {
        System.out.println("Authentication failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        authenticate t = new authenticate();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this

Comment: I have tried the suggestions given. It doesn't seem to work. I think it is the problem with the code rather than the IDE. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I have answered a very similar question on how to successfully set up an authenticated flickrj api instance here, I hope that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289552/how-to-access-private-photos-through-flickrj-api/15643638#15643638

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your interpretation of the strikeout that [getOriginalAsStream()](http://flickrj.sourceforge.net/api/com/aetrion/flickr/photos/Photo.html#getOriginalAsStream%28%29) is deprecated.  It looks like you might want to rework your code to use [PhotosInterface.getImageAsStream()](http://flickrj.sourceforge.net/api/com/aetrion/flickr/photos/PhotosInterface.html#getImageAsStream%28com.aetrion.flickr.photos.Photo,%20int%29), passing the ORIGINAL size as one of the arguments.

To adjust NetBeans' behavior with respect to deprecated methods, you can follow the link recommended by @AljoshaBre as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663221/where-can-i-find-the-xlint-option-in-netbeans).

Answer (score 0):

If you want download all your photos from Flickr, this is possible if you have a mac computer.
Download Aperture program on Apple Store and install it.
After to install, open the Aperture.
Go on preferences.
Click on 'Accounts' tab.
Click on plus sign (+) on bottom left to add a photo service.
Add the Flicker option.
Follow the login and authorization instructions.
Done! All your photos will be synchronized in you aperture library locate on ~/images/

I hope I have helped.